# Why it shows "User xxx is logged in on sshd“ warning when using shutdown close linux server?

Tags: linux, ssh, shutdown, visual-studio-code

I log a linux server by vscode's ssh method in Win10 (the terminal in vscode is like `(base) [myname@localhost ~]$` )and I am not a super user of this server (that means I cannot use `su`). When the server administrator used `shutdown -h` to close linux server, it shows,

> User xxx is logged in on sshd
>
> User xxx is logged in on sshd
>
> User xxx is logged in on sshd
>
> User xxx is logged in on sshd

P.S (xxx is my name).

Everytime he has to shutdown it by force option `poweroff -f`, but I want to know how to delele my logging info before shuting down linux server, I only know the instruct `w` and `kill`, but what about details? I tried to input `w` in vscode terminal but it shows 0 user.

By the way, I was confused about why it shows I am still logged in on sshd, because I always input `exit` in vscode terminal before I closing vscode. I have two terminals, `bash` and `Python debug Console`, in vscode, sometimes, I directly use 'kill terminal' by right clicking

Comment: @FrankThomas Hi, thanks for your reply, when I input `logout` in terminal in vscode it shows `bash: logout: not login shell: use exit`

Comment: Probably something you ran forked off and linger? Maybe he should check `loginctl user-status xxx` (assumimg systemd).

Comment: @TomYan Hi, it works and shows a tree including session and some status, what should I do next? by the way. if I only input `loginctl` it can shows a session num (2) , UID (1003) and myname, can I kill this uid directly to logout or clear info?

Comment: You can. See the man page of [`loginctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html). There are terminate/kill-session/user. What I was suggesting though was that the admin can check with the command and see if anything is keeping a session from ending after you have `exit`ed. (Btw, it's kinda weird that you logged in but bash isn't a login shell.)

Comment: BTW a tips, I found to close: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single SSH connection can carry multiple "channels" – interactive shells, non-interactive commands, SFTP, and so on. When you set up a remote connection via VSCode, even though you don't have any terminals open, the connection remains active because there is still a non-interactive data channel *to communicate with the remote VSCode server*.

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> `Remote: Close Remote Connection` command to fully disconnect.

Comment: Thanks, but what should I input in vscode terminal? I tried to input all `Remote: Close Remote Connection` but shows, `bash: Close: CommandNotFound...`

Comment: Nothing, it's the VSCode _command dialog_ (Ctrl-Shift-P) that has this command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to ask administrator to try it again